# Automatically adjusting axis range so that marker fits in Plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I'm stuck with this silly problem and can't solve it.
I need for several graphs to have the same x axis range (because they are shown on top of each other and have timestamp as x axis).
My first guess was to simply find the lowest and the highest of x values for all the plots and use them as x axis range for all of them.
It kinda works, but now the graphs look bad and the marker doesn't fit (see the picture).

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go

x1 = [1, 2, 3]
y1 = [1, 2, 1]
x2 = [1, 2]
y2 = [2, 1]
xmin = min(min(x1), min(x2))
xmax = max(max(x1), max(x2))
figure1=go.Figure(
    data=[
        go.Scatter(x=x1,
                   y=y1,
                   marker={'size': 20})
    ],
    layout={'xaxis': {'range': [xmin, xmax]}}
)
figure2=go.Figure(
    data=[
        go.Scatter(x=x2,
                   y=y2,
                   marker={'size': 20})
    ],
    layout={'xaxis': {'range': [xmin, xmax]}}
)
figure1.show()
figure2.show()
```

Is it possible to automatically adjust axis limits just enough for the marker to fit? Or maybe there is another solution for this task?

Thanks!

[image]

BTW, if I could just read what are the axis limits that plotly sets automatically, that would be very helpful

Comment: Data and code sample, please?

Comment: added a minimal (not) working example

Comment: Good! I'll try to have a look at it this afternoon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Option 1: Adjust xmin and xmax

In many cases you only need to add a little adjustments to your calculated `xmin` and `xmax`:

[image]

#### Option 2: adjust padding

You can create more space between the plotting area and the axis lines using the `pad` argument in `go.layout.Margin()`. You can adjust the setup further using the `l, r, t, b` arguments too.

[image]

```
# imports
import plotly.graph_objs as go

x1 = [1, 2, 3]
y1 = [1, 2, 1]
x2 = [1, 2]
y2 = [2, 1]
xmin = min(min(x1), min(x2))
xmax = max(max(x1), max(x2))

xmin_adjust = 0.5
xmax_adjust = 0.5

figure1=go.Figure(
    data=[go.Scatter(x=x1,
                     y=y1,
                    marker={'size': 20})],
    layout={'xaxis': {'range': [xmin-xmin_adjust, xmax+xmax_adjust]},
            'margin':go.layout.Margin(l=50, r=50, b=50, t=50, pad=50)})
            
figure2=go.Figure(
       data=[go.Scatter(x=x2,
                        y=y2,
                        marker={'size': 20})],
    
       layout={'xaxis': {'range': [xmin-xmin_adjust, xmax+xmax_adjust]},
            'margin':go.layout.Margin(l=50, r=50, b=50, t=50, pad=50)})
               
figure1.show()
figure2.show()
```

Comment: I could subtract and add some small values from xmin and xmax (0.5 in your example), but the problem is that I don't know in advance how big is the range. 
I.e. when x is from 1 to 3 adding 0.5 is enough, but if it is from 1000 to 3000 it will be too small a margin.

Comment: @Anna I'll take another look.

Comment: @Anna you could make the `xmin_adjust` relativ `to xmin` and the same for `xmas`  
like `xmin_adjust = xmin - (xmin/10)`  
so you get a 10 percent difference on the values

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add

```
figure1.update_layout(xaxis = dict(range=[0.9, 3.1]))
figure2.update_layout(xaxis = dict(range=[0.9, 2.1]))
```

before figure1.show() and figure2.show()